# How to get Bitmap from ImageView using Glide

Tags: android

How to convert Viewpager Image to Bitmap

```
val img = adapter.currentItem //return an int data type.
```

Comment: Introduce what you want to do and copy some code with issue.

Comment: Do you mean want to get bitmap of imageview in viewpager not the viewpager?

Comment: yes i wanted to convert or get bitmap from Viewpager imageView

Comment: Does your imageview using resource or url?

Comment: yes its used url , i am using glide to attact the url into imageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get bitmap of imageview with Glide aswell, the example is

```
Glide.with(this)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(yourURL)
    .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
            // you can use the bitmap here
        }
        override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {

        }
    })
```